# Problem while installing Mysql in the last step it's taking much time

Tags: mysql, configuration

[image: Error image]I tried to install MySQL but it's taking more time than usual time in the apply configuration part, Can someone help me out. I have attached screenshot for better clarification Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your Windows Firewall to allow MySQL and its components? I have run into this issue when installing on multiple Windows devices. Usually with Windows 10 there's a popup for you to allow MySQL yet sometimes there isn't for whatever odd reason. Try changing the firewall status or making an exception for MySQL.